Handling ReadTimeOut Exception with Spring Cloud Gateway/Netty Client
We are using Spring Cloud Gateway to route messages to different endpoints.
In some cases seeing read timeout happening and in hence is no "response" received resulting in wrapped 'WebClientRequestException' thrown.
Looking for ways to gracefully/custom handle timeouts, so that the request can be audited (with body/url etc)?
Appreciate any suggestions/inputs?
